# Blacklist System with MySQL in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have tried to create a blacklist system in Discord.js using MySQL.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM blacklist WHERE id_discord = "${member.user.id}"`, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (rows.length == 1){

    let raison = rows[1].raison;
    const banembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("#FF0000")
    .setTitle("Vous avez été bannit du serveur car vous faite partie de la blacklist !")
    .addField("Motif", raison)

    member.send(banembed);
    member.ban();
  }
}) });
```

Looks like it doesn't work, please help me.

Comment: To better understand the issue, enable DB logging to see if the query is correct, and please clarify what exactly doesn't work there, error logs is your friend

Answer (score 2):

Array indexes are zero-based, so you need to do `rows[0]` instead of `rows[1]`.